# Codomain of p-adic logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, logarithms, p-adic-number-theory

We have the natural map

$$\log: \mathbb{C}^\times \to \mathbb{R}$$

$$z \to \log |z|$$

**Is there a p-adic analogue of this?**

By this I mean, a map $\log_p: \mathbb{C}_p^\times \to \mathbb{Q}_p$, instead of the usual definition of p-adic logarithm, $\log_p: \mathbb{C}_p^\times \to \mathbb{C}_p$.

Comment: Why is this map natural (e.g. $z \mapsto \log |z|$)?

Answer (score 3):

I’m sure you’ve noticed that since $|z|_p$ is a *real* number, any logarithm of it is real. In fact, $-\log_p\bigl(|z|_p\bigr)$ is just what’s usually called the $p$-adic valuation of $z$, always an ordinary integer except when $z=0$. Often denoted $v_p(z)$.